# Python Days Delta: Remove time from days output in dataframe and convert column to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, timedelta

I have the following columns in a data frame.  The second column tells me the average number of days between activity dates per account.

The "Avg No. of Days Btw Activities" currently has a dtype of object.

[image]

Below is the code I wrote to create the second column:

```
df_act_8_date = pd.DataFrame(df_act_7_date.groupby("Account")["Avg No. of Days Btw Activities"].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()))
```

I would like for the second column to only show a number which represents the days and be a float value.  Please see the "Desired Column" for what I want to produce.

I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem.  I tried converting the second column to a float as a starter step but got the following Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15 days 07:26:53.793103448'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Avg No. of Days Btw Activitie'], errors='coerce').days
```

Demo:

```
In [160]: pd.to_timedelta(['99 days 12:00:05','AAA', '30 days 08:00:00.00000000'], 
                          errors='coerce').days
Out[160]: Float64Index([99.0, nan, 30.0], dtype='float64')
```